# Chosen JQuery Plugin get dropdown value during change

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

Multi-select Chosen JQuery plugin

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('select#cat').change(function()
  {
     alert($(this).val());
  });
});
</script>
```

I want selected value. But this alert not show.

```
<select id="cat" name="cat" class="chosen-select ref-sel1" multiple>
 <option value="1">cat1</option> 
 <option value="2">cat2</option>
 <option value="3">cat3</option>                    
</select>
```

Comment: `#cat !== #category`

Comment: sorry posted wrongly.. Now also not worked @jeroen

Comment: What is shown in the alert? Or does the alert not even appear?

Comment: alert box not appeared @Peanut

Comment: Try to open a "developer console" in your browser (if you work in Windows, press F12 in IE or Chrome, or install FireBug on Firefox) and check whether there are any entries in the console

Comment: Nothing display in Console area @Peanut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is wrong. You have some misplaced curly braces. Try with the following one:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
{
  $('select#cat').change(function()
  {
     alert($(this).val());
  })
});
```

The full script here: https://jsfiddle.net/jrh11mm4/4/

Comment: @shruthi Check out the link i have posted. Are you sure it is not working? Works fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: This worked in single select value, But i want Multi select value @demostene

Comment: @shruthi The link provided has exactly your html, including "multiple".

Answer (score 0):

According to the example from the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/) the following code should work:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $( "select" )
   .change(function () {
     var str = "";
     $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
       str += $( this ).text() + " ";
     });
     alert(str);
   });
 });
</script>
```

Note that you have to loop through all the selected items, in order to see whether they are selected or not.
I'm not sure why your alert did not show, but if it would have been displayed it should have been empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Chosen plugin, the select element is replaced by divs, so your jQuery check does not work. Try to research Chosen and see how to get the selected value.

I guess CHosenJS already has this functionality, for the multiple select boxes, where it turns options into removable tags.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 $(function() {
    $('#cat').change(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
        alert(selected);
   }); 
});
```